# Display UserName of user After logined using ajax form in mvc3 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

- i am working in mvc3 razor
- i have a partialview consisting form which is displayed as modal box :

  ```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",            UpdateTargetId ="result" , OnComplete = "onComplate()"}))
         {
          //forms
         }
  ```
- i have displayed username as Session["username"] in layout.cshtml
- But when i login through the partialview, it doesn't show the username ...
- How to do this .....plz help?

Comment: Do you want to display username after login in login form or always in layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the user name appears when you refresh the page.

Ajax will only update the targeted section. In your case the 'result' div. You also need to refresh the Session["username"] parent div also.

1. Put your session["username"] in a partial view and Wrap this view in a
   named parent div in you layout.
2. In your 'onComplete()' function i would make another ajax call to a update the parent div with the new partial view.

Answer (score 1):

**First.** In your post Login action, you firstly check user is valid or not. At that moment if user is valid, log in it, and save his `username` in session or cookie. It is for displaying username always in _Layout.

**Second.** If you want to display username, after login button clicked, in your onComplete() function.

```
OnComplete = "myOncomplete('#usernameDisplayerElement')"
```

And

```
function myOncomplete(id) {
        //display username
        $(id).text('@Html.Raw(Session["username"])');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just return the username as `ContentResult` within your ajax call and have it updated to your existing div as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult Login(string username, string password)
{
    // Your login logic, assuming it sets the below user identity
    return Content(string.Format("Hello {0}", HttpContext.User.Identity.Name));
}
```